# Parser/Lexer logical expression

Tags: parsing, expression, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I managed to write a parser/lexer with Antlr4 for logical expression.

The only issue I have, and I'm not able to resolve is the following:

Let's say I'm passing "~p & q" to my program. It will interpret this formula as "~(p & q)".
My problem is that I want "~p" interpreted as a negation of "p" in that case. But I also want "~(p & q)" to be interpreted correctly.

Here is my parser/lexer file:

```
grammar LogicFormula;

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

prog: expr+ ;

expr : expr op='&' expr # AND
     | expr op='|' expr # OR
     | expr op='->' expr # IMPLI
     | expr op='<->' expr # BIIMPLI
     | op='~' expr      # NOT
     | BOOL                 # bool
     | '(' expr ')'         # parens
     ;

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */
BOOL : [0-1]|[a-zA-Z];
AND : '&';
OR : '|';
NOT: '~';
IMPLI: '->';
BIIMPLI: '<->';
WS
    :   (' ' | '\r' | '\n') -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;
ErrorCharacter : . ;
```

Can someone help me with this please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Antl4 that's pretty simple, just reorder your `expr` rule:

```
expr : '(' expr ')'         # parens
     | op='~' expr          # NOT
     | expr op='&' expr     # AND
     | expr op='|' expr     # OR
     | expr op='->' expr    # IMPLI
     | expr op='<->' expr   # BIIMPLI
     | BOOL                 # bool
     ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Lucas, it did work and now my program interprets everything correctly.